# how to Make two parallel universe of site for javascript-enable and non-javascript-enable?

Tags: javascript, php, web-crawler, google-crawlers, noscript

I want to create two version of site that one of them work for **javascript-enabled** users and another for **non-javascript-enabled** . In the **javascript-enabled** version , i load all content using AJAX that crawlers cann't access to the content . I want to use below code to redirect page to **non-javascript-enabled** version :

```
<noscript>
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://example.org?noscript=true" />
</noscript>
```

Also i want to put some PHP scripts in the index page to check url parametrs .
This is my PHP codes :

```
<?php 
 if ($_GET['noscript'] == "true") {
  // This is non-javascript-enabled version
  // Show all content here using WP_QUERY function
}
?>
```

And now i have a question .
Does **google crawler** access to the content using **non-javascript-enabled** version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it does both. It definitely runs some JavaScript, but I've also seen it showing results for content inside `<noscript>` elements, so it'll probably work.

However, the HTML you've provided is *not valid*. Most browsers might accept it, but [it isn't strictly valid HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3610030/5223757). Instead, you should use a workaround from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3610030/5223757).

Thanks for trying to provide a non-JavaScript version of your site, though. Even if AJAX-fetched static content isn't the best way to create a website (it's often better to have all the content there but hide some of it with CSS), it's better that you're trying to provide a complete experience to everyone than leaving some people at the wayside.

Comment: Does google crawler access to content when even javascript is enabled  ?

Comment: Yes. I've no clue which version of the site it'll use to get the content, though.

Comment: Is this way good ?

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>This is a test page !</title>
    <?php
      if (!isset($_GET['jsenabled'])) {
        echo "<script>
          var hostorigin = window.location.origin;
          window.location.href = hostorigin + '/facecartesting.php?jsenabled=true';
        </script>";
      }
      ?>

  </head>
  <body>

<?php
  if (isset($_GET['jsenabled'])) {
    echo "JavaScript is  enabled !";
  } else {
    echo "JavaScript is disabled !";
  }
 ?>

  </body>
</html>`

Comment: @MortezaJamali That's a brilliant way of doing it! You should add that as an answer. One small improvement though; if your content is being put on the page _anyway_, you could set it up so that if JavaScript is enabled most of the elements are hidden and only one is shown at a time (or however you're doing it) and avoid having to have two different versions of your page.